# How to change grafana theme (dark|light) kubernetes deploy

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

How to set grafana theme in kubernetes deploy file. Is there any env variable supported. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to set any value in the Grafana config file with env variables.

```
GF_<SectionName>_<KeyName>
```

In your deployment.yaml file add the following:

```
env:
- name: GF_USERS_DEFAULT_THEME
  value: <dark/light>
```

[Defining env variables for a container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/) in Kubernetes.